# How to hide a specific element in a series by default

Tags: angular, typescript, amcharts4

I've created a stacked column chart in an angular application using Amcharts 4. I was wondering if there's a simple way to set a specific element in the legend series to be "hidden" by default. For example, I would like element1 to be "hidden" by default in the picture below.

stacked column picture

I understand how to hide the entire series using this method '.hide()' but not sure how to hide just a specific element from the series.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control if the series shows up in the lenged by setting `hiddenInLegend` like this: `series.hiddenInLegend = true;`.

This way you can easily handle what series should be shown in the legend.

I have created an example of a chart with the legend hidden for the first series. https://codepen.io/Kaehler/pen/ExoaOJY

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is it possible to still have series1 from your example appear in the legend, but toggled off?

Comment: Yes you can set that by setting the series to be `hidden` instead of `hiddenInLegend`, then it will be toggled off from the beginning: `series.hidden = true;`